# s3 folder permissions to get http requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 1 folder in this bucket with many subfolders.
I want to make it possible that (future) files in all folders are available within a browser (https get request).
Other buckets are listed as "objects can be public"

How can I do this through S3 console ?
regards,
w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting a specific folder within an Amazon S3 bucket to be public.

You can do this by adding a **Bucket Policy** to the S3 bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/folder-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This allows any object within `folder-name/` to be accessed (including sub-folders). The user would need to know the specific Key (filename) to access the object.

You would need to deactivate **S3 Block Public Access** before adding the Bucket Policy.

For more examples of Bucket Policies, see: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)